# Uncheck radio buttons on a multiple selection list. Improve performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, join, checked

I have created a filter list that depending the options that you choose, it displays one thing or another.

It does what it has to do, but it feels laggy and the reset button is horrible in performance (Especially on mobile) :(

this is the page: http://www.metagame.gg/champions/

I have been making the page fully responsive. The only problem now is this performance with the filters and reset.

For the filters i use this library: 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/2.2.2/isotope.pkgd.js

This is an example of the html code for checkboxes, Radio buttons and reset button:

```
// Radio buttons
<div id="selectorWrapper">
    <div id="selectorSection">Skill Ceiling</div>
    <div id="selectorContent">
        <div id="buttonWrapper">
            <label><input name="skill" type="radio" value=".Low" /> Low</label>
        </div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper">
            <label><input name="skill" type="radio" value=".Normal" /> Normal</label>
        </div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper">
            <label><input name="skill" type="radio" value=".High" /> High</label>
        </div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper">
            <label><input name="skill" type="radio" value=".Vhigh" /> Very High</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

//Checkboxes
<div id="selectorWrapperLast">
    <div id="selectorSection">Qualities</div>
    <div id="selectorContent">
        <div id="buttonWrapper">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value=".Ranged" /> Ranged</label>
        </div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value=".Melee" /> Melee</label>
        </div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value=".Crowd-Control" /> Crowd Control</label>
        </div>
        <div id="buttonWrapper">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value=".Engage" /> Engage</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how each item of the filtered list looks like:

```
<div class="item Engage Melee Low">
    <a href="...">
        <img class="champavatar" src="...png" alt="">
        <div class="textavatar">Champion</div> 
    </a>
</div>

// RESET
<div id="resetCheckboxesDiv">
    <button id="resetCheckboxes">Reset</button>
</div>
```

This is the script that filters everything and resets

```
$(function() {
    var
        e = $("#champavatars")
        .isotope({
            itemSelector: ".item"
        }),
        c = $("#output"),
        t = $("#selector input:radio"),
        n = $("#selector input:checkbox");

    t.add(n)
        .change(function() {
            var i = [],
                o = [];

            t.each(function(e, c) {
                c.checked && i.push(c.value)
                }),

                n.each(function(e, c) {
                    c.checked && i.push(c.value)
                }),

                i = i.join("");
            var u;
            o.length ? (u = $.map(o, function(e) {
                    return e + i
                }),
                u = u.join(", ")) : u = i, c.text(u), e.isotope({
                filter: u
            })
        }),

        //RESET EVERYTHING
        $("#resetCheckboxes")
        .click(function() {
            n.attr("checked", !1)
                .change(), t.attr("checked", !1)
                .change()
        })
});
```

Thank you very much in advance, i am still newbie with javascript so any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: it doesn't seem 'laggy' at all, can you be more specific?  I just clicked around, reset seems fast too

Comment: in mobile the reset button ocassionally crashes the browser